# How to continuously tail a log, find all files (sed), and display (cat) the found files

Tags: sed, tail

How to I continuously `tail -f` a log, find all files (`sed`), and display (`cat`) the found files

### example data in audit logs.

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/modsec_audit.log | sed 's/[^\/]*/\./;s/].*$//g'
```

#### output

```
./apache/20180508/20180508-1428/20180508-142802-WvH6QgoeANwAAMwsFZ4AAAAF
./apache/20180508/20180508-1428/20180508-142803-WvH6QgoeANwAAMwtFfcAAAAG
./apache/20180508/20180508-1428/20180508-142803-WvH6QwoeANwAAMwuFlUAAAAH
./apache/20180508/20180508-1513/20180508-151357-WvIFBQoeANwAAMwnE@4AAAAA
./apache/20180508/20180508-1513/20180508-151357-WvIFBQoeANwAAMwoFD8AAAAB
./apache/20180508/20180508-1516/20180508-151608-WvIFiAoeANwAAMz1FSwAAAAA
./apache/20180508/20180508-1516/20180508-151609-WvIFiQoeANwAAMz2FYIAAAAB
./apache/20180508/20180508-1516/20180508-151611-WvIFiwoeANwAAMz3FeEAAAAC
./apache/20180508/20180508-1516/20180508-151611-WvIFiwoeANwAAMz4Fj4AAAAD
./apache/20180508/20180508-2112/20180508-211205-WvJY9QoeANwAAM1MFCoAAAAA
```

#### works with echo

```
echo "./apache/20180508/20180508-1428/20180508-142802-WvH6QgoeANwAAMwsFZ4AAAAF" | sed 's/[^\/]*/\./;s/].*$//g' | awk '{print $0}' | xargs cat
```

#### works with cat

```
cat /var/log/httpd/modsec_audit.log | sed 's/[^\/]*/\./;s/].*$//g' | awk '{print $0}' | xargs cat
```

#### does not work with tail...

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/modsec_audit.log | sed 's/[^\/]*/\./;s/].*$//g' | awk '{print $0}' | xargs cat
```

I assume the tailing does not work because the script never terminates and `sed` is still caching the results until termination of the script.

***Is there a way to make this work, continuously?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffering is getting in the way.

Use a `while read line` from the shell, which should read line-by-line and avoid most problems with buffering:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/modsec_audit.log | while read line; do
    echo "$line" | sed 's/[^\/]*/\./;s/].*$//g' | awk '{print $0}' | xargs cat
done
```

Though you can probably do better than that, by using shell (bash) to match the filename from the log line too:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/modsec_audit.log | while read line; do
    line=${line/*([^\/])/.}
    line=${line%]*}
    [[ -n "${line}" ]] && cat "${line}"
done
```

Comment: Not only buffering, plain `xargs` would read as many arguments as possible before executing `cat`. `xargs -n 1 cat` may solve that.

Comment: I like it! Is there a way to break out of the loop if i put this into a custom method?

Comment: @Artistan You can call `break` from within the `while` loop, that will work. If using a language such as Python is an option for you as well, that gives you even more flexibility to process the log file. Google for it, you'll find implementations of `tail -f` in Python that you can reuse.

Comment: Thanks again @FilipeBrandenburger. - my result is here, if you have any suggestions for improvements https://gist.github.com/Artistan/981e4b20e539b092b018fa1ad20e1219

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/modsec_audit.log | stdbuf -oL sed 's/[^\/]*/\./;s/].*$//g' | stdbuf -oL awk '{print $0}' | while IFS='' read -r file; do cat $file ; done
```